# Как сделать слайдер с видео с помощью waterwheel carousel?

Tags: javascript, видео, карусель

Всем привет. Нужно сделать слайдер, который будет содержать видео. 
Я использую плагин [Waterwheel Carousel](http://www.bkosborne.com/jquery-waterwheel-carousel). Используя изображение, все работает. Но как только я использую `<video>`, то все сразу перестает работать.

```
<div class="wrapper_video_review">
    <div class="video_review">
        <video src="video/video.mp4" controls="controls"></video>
        <video src="video/video.mp4" controls="controls"></video>
        <video src="video/video.mp4" controls="controls"></video>
        <video src="video/video.mp4" controls="controls"></video>
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(".video_review").waterwheelCarousel({
  flankingItems: 3
});
```

Comment: или посоветуйте похожую карусель, где можно использовать видео.

Comment: Может там идет привязка к тегу img, а ты ему video суешь... вот и не работает....